# Using getchar() to exit a loop when user hits 'Enter'?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, do-while

I have read a lot of other stack overflow topics on this but I am still having a lot of trouble. I have tried to use a do/while loop as well as a nested if statement. I can't get the last if to stop printing 'cards' when the the 'player' hits 'enter'. Ether the getchar() holds up the if statement so that is will only print if the user continually presses enter (which is not even close to what I am intending) or it just continues to print after pausing.

```
void printDeck(Card *deck, const char *faces[], const char *suits[], FILE *fp)
{
    int loop, t;
    // print the deck one card at a time

    fp = fopen("cardsprinted.txt", "w+");
    t = ftell(fp);
    char c;
    do {
        c = getchar();    
        for (loop = 0; loop < 52; loop++) {
            // print the face and suit of the card to stdout as well as file
            printf("%s of %s\n",faces[deck[loop].face],suits[deck[loop].suit]);
            fprintf(fp,"%s of %s\n",faces[deck[loop].face],suits[deck[loop].suit]);
            fseek(fp, t, SEEK_SET); // finds beginning of the file
            fseek(fp,t,SEEK_END);// finds end of file for printing

            // loop to pause for 3seconds before printing next card. 
            if ((loop % 1) == 0 && loop != 0) { 
                sleep(3);
            }
        }
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

output examples:

```
./slapjack
Queen of Spades
Nine of Spades
Jack of Hearts
```

this is where I hit enter and want the loop to stop printing.

```
Three of Hearts
Queen of Hearts
Six of Spades
Seven of Diamonds
^C
```

but it doesn't work...

I have also tried not using getchar(). I thought maybe scanf() would be easier but still no luck.

Comment: `c` should be an `int`, not a `char`.  This is because `EOF` has to be (and is) different from any value that `getchar()` can return, so you need more bits of storage than just a `char` can provide.

Comment: If you mean that you want someone to be able to press a key "in real time" that you can detect, but the program has to keep running if they don't press a key - that's not possible with Standard C, you will have to make an operating system call, or use a library such as `ncurses` that can read the keyboard without inputting a whole line.

Comment: You will need to put `STDIN` into non-blocking mode, or spawn a `pthread` to block on `stdin`, and give a semaphore which you will try to acquire in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while statement.

set a control var to true

Before entering, test for getchar if detected set control var to false

enter while loop

psudocode below:

```
controlvar = ! getchar()

while (controlvar) {
  do something
  test for end condition or getchar to set controlvar false
}
```